# Why does Kubernetes showing the nodes as ready even if they are not reachable?

Tags: kubernetes

I am running Kubernetes cluster which is configured with a master and 3 nodes.

```
#kubectl get nodes
NAME       STATUS    AGE
minion-1   Ready     46d
minion-2   Ready     46d
minion-3   Ready     46d
```

I have launched couple of pods in the cluster and found that the pods are in pending state.

```
# kubectl get pods -o wide
NAME      READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE       IP        NODE
httpd     0/1       Pending   0          10m       <none>
nginx     0/1       Pending   0          11m       <none>
```

One of the pod "httpd" yaml file:

```
# cat http.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: httpd
  labels:
    env: test
spec:
  containers:
  - name: httpd
    image: httpd
```

While debugging the reason for failure found that the couple of nodes configured are not ready. Only one node is reachable from master.

```
# ping minion-1
PING minion-1 (172.31.24.204) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from minion-1 (172.31.24.204): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.575 ms
```

Whereas other nodes are not reachable:

```
# ping minion-2
PING minion-2 (172.31.29.95) 56(84) bytes of data.
From master (172.31.16.204) icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable

# ping minion-3
PING minion-3 (172.31.17.252) 56(84) bytes of data.
From master (172.31.16.204) icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
```

The queries that I have here is

> 1) Why does Kubernetes showing the nodes as ready even if they are not
>   reachable from master?
>
> 2) Why are the pods creation failing?

```
  Is it because of unavailability of nodes or any configuration issue in yaml file?

#  kubectl describe pod httpd
Name:           httpd
Namespace:      default
Node:           /
Labels:         env=test
Status:         Pending
IP:
Controllers:    <none>
Containers:
  httpd:
    Image:                      httpd
    Port:
    Volume Mounts:              <none>
    Environment Variables:      <none>
No volumes.
QoS Class:      BestEffort
Tolerations:    <none>
No events.
```

Following are the Kubernetes and etcd versions.

```
]# kubectl --version
Kubernetes v1.5.2
[root@raghavendar1 ~]# et
etcd        etcdctl     ether-wake  ethtool
[root@raghavendar1 ~]# etcd --version
etcd Version: 3.2.5
Git SHA: d0d1a87
Go Version: go1.8.3
Go OS/Arch: linux/amd64
```

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes do not use ICMP protocol to check nodes master node connectivity.

Nodes become `Ready` when the communication `node` -> `api-server` works and this is done via `https` protocol.

You can read more about about node - master connectivity in kubernetes documentation https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/master-node-communication/

Why `pod` isn't scheduled? 
The answer to this question is in the `master` logs probably, check `kube-apiserver.log`, `kube-scheduler.log`. The reason is cluster misconfiguration.

For start run it in a single network to get a grip of things and double check routing.

Comment: As you said the communication is done via https protocol, but does it mean that it checks only the initial connectivity but not the aliveness of the node ?